# Get key of type UUID and compare to string value

Tags: java, string, hashmap, uuid

I have a HashMap of type UUID and token. The UUID is the key. I want to get the keys as a String and compare it to another String.
Here my Hashmap :

```
private final Map<UUID,Token> token = new HashMap<>();
```

and then I want e.g

```
token.containsKey(string) = true
```

but it wont work like this.

And I want to extract the key value (UUID) and compare it to a string. So it should compare these two. I have tried for loops and with `containsKey()` but it did not work. Has anyone a solution to this?

Thanks in regard

Comment: Hi & Welcome! Please have a look at [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) - as on [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html) javadocs. The latter offers "conversion functions" to/from strings, the first offers general documentation & "conventions" of a `java.util.Map` (key, value, ..., equals, hashCode...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I Understand, in a given `UUID` as a key, you want from it's String value get it's Token Value?

So for example:

```
public boolean isContains(String uuidAsString, Map<UUID, Token> tokenMap) {
    UUID key = UUID.fromString(uuidAsString);  // Parse input string as a UUID object.
    return tokenMap.containsKey(key);  // Look for that UUID object among the map’s keys.
}
```

Pay attention that `fromString` can throws `IllegalArgumentException` if name does not conform to the string representation of `UUID`

Comment: thanks alot this helped me enormous